# Grant truncate privilege to some tables of different user in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How to Grant truncate privilege to some tables of a different user in Oracle and same ..How we can do this in Oracle 11 g..Anyone please help on this

Comment: create a stored proc that will truncate the table/s and then grant execute to the user/s   https://community.oracle.com/thread/644912?tstart=0

Answer (score 4):

create a procedure that can truncate a table,

```
create or replace procedure do_truncate (tab_name in varchar2) as
begin
  --For safety, only allow truncating a specific list of tables.
  if tab_name in ('TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3') then
    execute immediate 'truncate table '||tab_name;
  else
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'The table '||tab_name||' is not allowed to be truncated.');
  end if;
end;
/

grant execute on do_truncate to Dave;
```

Comment: No....no.... no...... (Creating a procedure is the correct solution but blindly allowing it to truncate any table is just asking for issues down the line when someone truncates a table that you did not intend them to have access to. Either have one procedure per table and grant access to the minimum required procedures or you should put in some sort of checking process that the user has permissions to truncate the table with that name).

Comment: They asked for procedure. There was not any requirements about security, but it also caught mu attention.

Comment: The OP asked "How to Grant truncate privilege to some tables" - *some* not *all*.

Comment: Also: some not one.

Comment: I never said just one - I said "have one procedure per table and grant access to the minimum required procedures".

Comment: And i said - there was nothing about security. Feel free to write your own answer :)

Comment: A table can be prepared with the columns table_name and username and entries can be made into it to map which user can truncate which tables. In the procedure same table can be referred to find out the truncate privs. I believe everyone will have this in mind but just mentioning it as it has not been mentioned anywhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Formal permission is "drop any table".

Dangerous though.